# Exception on flutter of length called on null on api put call

Tags: json, database, api, flutter, exception

I tried to call put API in postman software, it worked there. I send data with Bearer Token in the Authorization tab. But when I tried the same thing using HTTP function in Flutter, an exception is caught saying "the getter "length" was called on null", where as I have not used any length or list in the data.

```
Future<void>EditProfile(PublisherEdit p)async{
  // http.Response response;
  print("Hello");
  // print(p.username+p.phone+p.content_type+p.pricesPeriod+p.pricesAmount);
  // print(userdata.user.token);
  try{
    // print("hllllo");
    dynamic response = await http.put("http://newsbagserver-env.eba-ymb65tjc.us-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/publishers/5fce6bbe09f4e82b6b2f9bf9",
  body: {
    "username" : "abc",
    "phone" : "abc",
    "photo" : p.photo,
    "content_type" : "abc",//p.content_type,
    "frequency":"abc",
    "bank":"abc",
    "account_name":"abc",
    "account _number":"abc",
      },
      headers: {
        // 'Content-Type': 'application/form-data',
        // 'Accept': 'application/json',
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: userdata.user.token,
      },
    );
    print("hel"+response.body);
  }catch(e){
    print("Hello1");
    print("error" + e.toString());
  }
  // print("hel"+response.body);
}
```

I have edited a screenshot of arising exception:

[image]

Comment: Where do you call the length of something in your project?

Comment: Are you sure the error is thrown during the execution of this piece of code? Does it print "Hello" and/or "hel[respondbody]" in your debug console? You can also use breakpoints in your IDE to find out.

Comment: I aint calling any length, have tested and printed variables. @Akif

Comment: Yes it print hello and but not response.body bcz then there's a problem in try block and it jumps on to catch block and prints this error @cumul

Comment: It worked when tried sending body as jsonEncode